# Convert Timestamp in Azure Data Factory to parquet timestamp format

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, parquet, azure-machine-learning-service

Using Azure Data Factory, I am attempting to save data in parquet format. The save of data works, however, I cannot save a Timestamp field with the correct precision. My understanding is that it needs to be UNIX epoch format.

Azure ML Studio will consume the file; therefore, the data types need to be correct in the parquet file when it leaves the data factory.

The format of the timestamp in the source data is as follows:

> yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm:ss

> 2023-05-08 12:33:00

Using the Dataflow expression builder, I've tried the following:

```
toTimestamp(byName('datareceivedtimestamp'))
```

In the data preview in ADF this outputs the correct timestamp of type 'timestamp' (2023-05-08 12:33:00.000) but when saved as parquet the data is lost.
**2023-05-08 12:33:00** becomes **45180000000000** for some reason.

```
toLong(datareceivedtimestamp - toTimestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') ) * 1000l
```

This results in the correct UNIX EPOCH timestamp; however, the data type is long. (no good for Azure ML)

Using Azure data flow expression, how can I correctly save my timestamp as a parquet-compatible timestamp recognised as a timestamp/datetime in the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory currently writes timestamps to Parquet as `INT96`.

This will transform and save the timestamp:

1. **Convert the timestamp to the correct format**:

   - Since you have your timestamp in the format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm:ss', first convert it into a more standard format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'.

     ```
     toTimestamp(replace(byName('datareceivedtimestamp'), '-', ':'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
     ```
2. **Derive the Unix epoch timestamp**:

   - Convert the above timestamp into Unix epoch format (milliseconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000').

     ```
     toLong((yourColumnName - toTimestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')) * 1000L)
     ```
3. **Convert the Unix epoch timestamp back to a timestamp**:

   - Now, convert this long Unix epoch value back into a timestamp. This might sound redundant, but the goal is to trick ADF into treating this value as a legitimate timestamp and thus store it with the correct precision in Parquet.

     ```
     toDate(yourUnixEpochColumnName)
     ```
4. **Sink Transformation**:

   - Now, write this timestamp to your Parquet sink. Make sure in the mapping section of your sink transformation, the data type of this column is set to `timestamp`.